# jQuery Extend to anonymous object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

While trying to get some idea of how jQueryUI is made, i saw in the code that they used the `extend` utility. however, it was used to extend an anonymous object.

can anyone explain it, please?

```
$.fn.extend({
    scrollParent: function( includeHidden ) {
        var position = this.css( "position" ),
            excludeStaticParent = position === "absolute",
 /// and the code goes on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery.fn.extend()**

As the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) states, `jQuery.fn.extend()` method

> Merge the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.

So, your code extends jQuery's prototype (**fn** is just an **alias to jQuery's prototype**) by adding the method `scrollParent`

You can call this new method to any jQuery object like this:

```
$('#myElement').scrollParent(includeHidden);
```

---

**jQuery.extend()**

`jQuery.extend( object1, object2 )` just merges object2 in to object1

Check the [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) documentation for more detail

Comment: Got it. `$.extend` is not similar to `$.fn.extend`

Comment: The first extends an object that you provide, the second extends the jQuery's prototype

Answer (score 1):

The code is extending `$` (which is the same as the `jQuery` object), so `$.scrollParent` is now a function. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/).

Here's an example too, from that very page.

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.extend({
  check: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  },
  uncheck: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

// Use the newly created .check() method
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).check();
</script>
```